# How to write complex JOIN query in CDbCriteria Yii Framework

Tags: php, sql, yii

I have two tables : `product` and `document` and both are in relations with document_id.

Now I want to fetch documents name by `product_id` from database using Yii CDbCriteria.

Like :

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM `document` As d, `product_document` AS p 
WHERE d.document_id=p.document_id
AND
p.product_id=133;
```

I want to write same query but using `CDbCriteria`. I have tried it but I am getting stuck with its syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Harry has the right syntax. If you want to make it cleaner and more reuseable throughout your app, consider using a named scope:

```
/* scope in your Document model */
public function forProductId($id) {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->condition = 'product.id = :productId',
    $criteria->with = 'product';
    $criteria->params = array(
        ':productId' => (int)$id,
    );
    return $this->dbCriteria()->mergeWith($criteria);
}
```

Makes your setup far more reuseable over time ...

Comment: +1 for a nice use case of a [parameterized named scope](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes). For completeness: @Glenn, you should put this method into your `Document` model and can then use it like `$documents = Document::model()->forProductId($id)->findAll()`.

Comment: @MichaelHärtl Thanks.  I'm working on a project where I run into this type of criteria code all the time, I've been working on encouraging my co-workers to make the shift, it's invaluable ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is your criteria, assuming that you have relations set up correctly:

```
$c = Document::model()->getDbCriteria();
$c->with[] = 'product';
$c->addCondition('product.product_id = :product_id');
$c->params[':product_id'] = 133;
```